# socket.io redis and memory leak

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

My socket.io version is socket.io@0.8.7 and redis@0.7.1.
I am on Windows.

In some places, I have seen that the issue is solved. I suppose I am using the latest socket.io version.
what is emitter.setMaxListeners() and where can I set it ?

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added.
Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace:
    at RedisClient.<anonymous> (events.js:133:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\HTML5\LIKEPREF\test\server\server.js:576:18)
    at Socket.$emit (events.js:67:17)
    at SocketNamespace.handlePacket (C:\Personal\software\nodejs\NODE\node_modul
es\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:335:22)
    at Manager.onClientMessage (C:\Personal\software\nodejs\NODE\node_modules\so
cket.io\lib\manager.js:459:38)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Personal\software\nodejs\NODE\node_modules\socket
.io\lib\transport.js:387:20)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (C:\Personal\software\nodejs\NODE\node_modules\socket.
io\lib\transports\websocket\hybi-16.js:40:10)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at C:\Personal\software\nodejs\NODE\node_modules\socket.io\lib\transports\we
bsocket\hybi-16.js:286:16
    at Parser.expectHandler (C:\Personal\software\nodejs\NODE\node_modules\socke
t.io\lib\transports\websocket\hybi-16.js:297:15)
```

I am using redis pubsub and when i am subscribing to redis, at that point it throws up this warning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a known issue associated with this. Looks like it was patched several months ago. The easiest fix is to set the maximum listeners to 0 which will remove the actual limit. So it would look something like this:

```
this.sub = redis.createClient(opts.redisSub.port, opts.redisSub.host, opts.redisSub);
this.sub.setMaxListeners(0);
```

You can find the full discussion here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/520

Comment: Mike Thanks. According to the discussion, it should be this.sub.maxListeners(0), instead of this.sub.setMaxListeners(0); Anyway let me try and will update you.

Comment: Mike, just tested. it should be setMaxListeners(0) and not maxListeners(0). seems to be working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Is this still relevant in 2023?