# when using socket.io with redis getting warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected.11 message listeners added

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

Complete Error Msg.I get this error when using socket.io and redis.All are latest packages.I run v4.5.0 node.

> (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message
>   listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit at
>   RedisClient.addListener

I get this error message if I reload the browser several times.I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306191/socket-io-redis-and-memory-leak) that is quite old and it is mentioned it was patched.

FYI I am running three instances of node behind a nginx proxy.

> app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var redis = require('redis');
var redisClient = redis.createClient();
var sub = redis.createClient();
var pub = redis.createClient();
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
app = express();
var io = require('socket.io')();

var sessionMiddleware = session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    client:redisClient
  }),
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
});

io.use(function(socket, next) {
  sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});

app.io = io;
app.use(sessionMiddleware);

//sub.setMaxListeners(0);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  sub.subscribe('chat');

  socket.on('chat', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    pub.publish('chat', data.msg);
  });

  sub.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    console.log(channel, message);
    socket.emit(channel, message);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
     //sub.quit()
     //sub.unsubscribe("chat");
     //I tried both above, for sub.quit() throwing error already closed.
  });
});
```

I have added only the code required related to redis,socket.io and sessions.

> bin/www

```
var app = require('../app');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = app.io;
io.listen(server);
server.listen(port);
```

[image]

> Is this really a fix or workaround `sub.setMaxListeners(0);`.Am I doing something wrong that causes the leak.This code fixes that warning.But If I reload the browser several times and
>   enter a message.I get it several times in the terminal.
>   Added Picture above for reference.

```
chat-channelName hello-msg
```